# Cannot Get MVVM Light EventToCommand to Work

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, .net-4.5.2

I am having trouble getting MVVM Light `EventToCommand` to work. I currently have these packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Expression.Blend.Sdk" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MvvmLightLibs" version="5.2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

and this is my code in the XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
      <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DragMoveCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Every time I run it, I get an error saying:

Could not load file or assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform, PublicKeyToken=5f873c45e98af8a1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am currently running .NET 4.5.2, and am not sure what else to do to get this to work.  All and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [System.Windows.Interactivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity(v=expression.40).aspx) version that used in you project and the version that used in GalaSoft library, if you didn't referenced to `System.Windows.Interactivity` you should refer to. in your project, if not helps try to clean your solution and remove all `obj` folders in your project directory and re-refer to `GalaSof`t library.